# How to perform variance decomposition?

Tags: variance, stata, decomposition

suppose I have the variable X, and I simply want to know how much of the variance of X is explained by the other variables Y, Z and W. How can I do this in Stata? I have in mind a simple linear model, no random effects

Comment: Not Strata, but in R you can try: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/relaimpo.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at the unadjusted $R^2 = 1 - \frac{RSS}{TSS}$ or compare the Model SS with Total SS (since $MSS =TSS - RSS$):

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. reg price weight mpg 

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 71)        =     14.74
       Model |   186321280         2  93160639.9   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   448744116        71  6320339.67   R-squared       =    0.2934
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2735
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =      2514

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |   1.746559   .6413538     2.72   0.008      .467736    3.025382
         mpg |  -49.51222   86.15604    -0.57   0.567    -221.3025     122.278
       _cons |   1946.069    3597.05     0.54   0.590    -5226.245    9118.382
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. display  186321280/635065396
.29338912

. display e(mss)/(e(mss)+e(rss))
.29338912

. display  e(r2)
.29338912
```

These will all be equivalent with an OLS model.